# Error while using ng2-Chart in asp.net mvc 6

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc, systemjs, ng2-charts

I am facing issue while using ng2-charts. [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9hw1.png)

here is my systemjs config code

```
<script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                app: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
        System.import('app/boot')
              .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```

> angular2-polyfills.js:138 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < Evaluating localhost:48512/ng2-charts/ng2-charts Error loading localhost:48512/app/boot.jsrun @ angular2-polyfills.js:138 Failed to parse SourceMap: localhost:48512/js/system.js.map

[image]

Comment: What error? . . ..

Comment: click on Error image I attached the image Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: It would be better to add images inline instead of linking to external resources. In addition adding the error message as text would also be a good idea for other devs that run into the same issue to be able to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and was able to resolve it by adding the following to my systemjs.config file

```
packages: {
        app: {
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            meta: {
                './*.js': {
                    loader: 'src/systemjs-angular-loader.js'
                }
            }
        },
        rxjs: { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'ng2-charts': {
            main: 'ng2-charts.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    }
});
```

I encountered some other hurdles configuring the library which I documented here http://spartansoft.net/installing-ng2-charts-for-an-angular-4-project/. Hopefully it can help others.